# Printing an Array List full of a new type of object

Tags: java, class, arraylist, iterator

I am working on a Java program, where I have an ArrayList called "CD" and inside this CD there are "Songs", and each song is an object in my Song class, and it has the arguments: String artist, String album, and int year. Any general suggestions about how to print this such that it also prints the contents of each song?

P.S. I know there are similar questions on here but I am still having trouble getting it to print exactly what I am wanting it to, and I have tried using iterator.

Thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: Show us your iterator attempt. Or put a `toString()` method in your `Song` class.

Comment: Yes please share more info and the code you have written so far, it is impossible to know what code would help without more details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use foreach

```
for (Song s:CD) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

And in your Song class, add the following:

```
public String toString() {
    return artist+" "+album+" "+year;
}
```

When you print an object, the printer first looks to the toString method, which is inherited by every object from the class Object. Overriding the toString method, changes representation of the given object.

Lastly, I'd recommend your songs had a field "name". I mean, isn't that the most important part of the printable data?

Comment: Yes, I can't believe I forgot that. So when would one want to use the Iterator class instead of using a for each loop?

Comment: @user2465406 well, let's say you have a matrix of integers that you want to fill with some random values. So you have 
    
    int i[n][n];

if you go through foreach loop, you wouldn't be able to "fill" the matrix, without some outside iterator. So, a for loop (or two in this case) are much more useful.

Foreach can be used whenever you don't want to "feed" another array. If you need a minimum value from some integer arrays, or if you're printing stuff, like here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `toString()` method in your `Song` class.

Without this method implemented, Java will only print the reference address of the object.
For your `Song`class, the  `toString()` method could look like this:

```
public String toString(){
    return "Artist:"+artists+", Song name:"+ songName+", Album:"+album+", Year:"+year;
}
```

After that, you can simply print your array with
`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cd));`

Comment: Also, this makes sense since I was getting address values

Answer (score 1):

Write as toString() method in your Song class

```
public String toString()
{
   return artist + " " + album + " " + year;
}
```

then call the method toString().Example System.out.println(MyList.toString())

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Lombok @ToString annotation over your Songs class. Incase you feel too lazy to write your own toString method.